# Passing Azure Key Vault Secret to Services.Configure in Blazor App

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, dependency-injection, blazor

I'm having difficulty passing an azure KeyVault Secret to my Database Settings configuration.

My code is as follows:
Program.cs

```
var keyVaultEndPoint = new Uri(builder.Configuration["VaultKey"]);
var secretClient = new SecretClient(keyVaultEndPoint, new DefaultAzureCredential());

KeyVaultSecret kvs = secretClient.GetSecret(builder.Configuration["SecretName"]);

var database = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Database");

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
    
builder.Services.Configure<DatabaseSettings>(
builder.Configuration.GetSection("Database"));

builder.Services.AddSingleton<TodoService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<RecipesService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<SpecialDatesService>();
```

appsettings.Json

```
"Database": {
    "ConnectionString": null,
    "DatabaseName": "Personal",
    "TodoCollectionName": "todo",
    "RecipesCollectionName": "recipes",
    "SpecialDatesCollectionName": "specialdates"
  },
```

Im getting the correct connection string at kvs.Value, but i have no idea how can i set it in the DatabseSettings configure.

Any ideas?

My goal is to have the keyvault secret being somehow inject in that DatabaseSettings Object which is being used by my services.

Comment: where are you using kvs  or kvs.value to pass that to service ?

Comment: I think you are looking for following couple of lines where you need to pass the kvs.value in the options to store in connection string . builder.Services.Configure<DatabaseSettings>(options =>
{
    options.ConnectionString = kvs.value;
    builder.Configuration.GetSection("Database").Bind(options);
});

Answer (score 2):

builder.Services.Configure(options => { options.ConnectionString = kvs.Value; builder.Configuration.GetSection("Database").Bind(options); });

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).